# Android material CardView ripple effect changes content color

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I recently moved from using custom card components to material design 3 cards. To my surprise, the ripple color, when pressing on the card, changes the content color. I tried this on the catalog project of the material-design-components repository and the card behaves the same way. My current code for changing the ripple color and the card background:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Card.Filled" parent="Widget.Material3.CardView.Filled">
   <item name="rippleColor">#4D4D4D</item>
   <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I also got a demo showing this behavior: https://i.imgur.com/t4WW4CY.mp4. The font color changes to a light gray based on the ripple effect. I am also using material buttons but there the ripple effect is not affecting the content. I am using the version `1.5.0-rc01`.

Does anyone have an idea if that is intended and how I can only change the background color on press using the attributes given by the material design components.

**Update:**

My card view XML (its the one from the [material-components github](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/card/res/layout/cat_card_states_fragment.xml#L26) + custom style):

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      style="@style/Widget.App.Card.Filled"
      android:id="@+id/card"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.4"
      android:layout_margin="16dp"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="true"
      app:contentPadding="@dimen/cat_card_content_padding">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cat_card_states_card_content"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"/>
  </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: can you share your card view xml code ?

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because of the ripple color applying to the foreground instead of background. So yeah this is intended and i don't think you can change that.

Have a look at the source code : [MaterialCardViewHelper.java](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/7665730a0befae42a15c89ba5c1082a5e98442ad/lib/java/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardViewHelper.java#L644)

**Note :** This does not happen in buttons bcoz buttons applies ripple to the background instead of foreground.

Source code for button : [MaterialButtonHelper.java](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/7665730a0befae42a15c89ba5c1082a5e98442ad/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButtonHelper.java#L260)